# UITextView not shown

Tags: ios, uitextview, invisible

I have a `UITextView` in a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Sometimes, when I edit the `UITextView` text and delete all the text and save; then the `UITableView` will reload the data and now the `UITextView` is not visible in the cell.

Its showing as follows.  In the second cell, there is no `UITextView` also there is no gap between the label and the cell separator.

This is happening sometimes, especially when there is no text in the `UITextview`.

---

Label1

UITextView

---

Label2

---

Label3

UITextView.

---

What could be the issue here ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // grab the reusable cell and fill it with data
    MyCustomViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DefaultCell"];
    [cell setName:nameSet[indexPath.row]];
    [cell setDescription:descriptionSet[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

And I have given the following while initializing :

```
    m_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0f;
m_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: share all the source code that you use to manage the tableView

Comment: Share your cellforRow methos's code. Issue might be there

Comment: share some code.

Comment: Have u managed textviewheight according to text in textviewdidchange ??

Comment: I have not managed textviewheight.

Comment: Have you disabled scrolling for your `UITextView`? Is your `setDescription` method doing anything other than setting the text of your text view?

Comment: @DonMag, Yes DonMag the scrolling is disabled while UITextView is created. Is it why this is happening ?  I will try by enabling the scrolling.

Comment: @RajendraBatta - no, scrolling *should* be disabled. I can't replicate your issue...

Comment: Can you show any code you're running in the cell? Are you changing the size of the text view while editing? How are you saving the edited text?

Comment: I have an object in the cell, on which I call to update the text. I will call update the text in the textViewDidEndEditing event. And now I am making the textview disabled for userinteraction.  After the update is done, there will be reloadData call on the table.